# three.js lookAt() : how to point some local axis which *isn't* the positive Z axis towards another object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating an app where a person (right now I'm using a cone-shape) is standing on some surface (right now I'm using a cylinder laid lengthwise) and I'd like their feet to orient toward some point (right now it's the center of the cylinder).

[image: The intended result.] (**edit**: I just realized that my Z axis in this photo is pointing in the wrong direction; it should be pointing *towards* the camera, but the question remains unchanged.)

Here is a version of the code similar to what I'm trying to accomplish. https://codepen.io/liamcorbett/pen/YMWayJ (Use arrow keys to move the cone)

```
//...

person = CreatePerson();
person.mesh.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

//
// ...
// 

function updateObj(obj, aboutObj=false){
    let mesh = obj.mesh;
    if (aboutObj) {
        mesh.lookAt(
            aboutObj.mesh.position.x, 
            aboutObj.mesh.position.y, 
            mesh.position.z)
    };
}

//
// ...
//

function animate() {
    // ...

    updateObj(person);

    // ...
}
```

The code above gives me something similar to what I'm looking for, but the issue is that lookAt() seems to always point the local **Positive Z-axis** in some direction, and I'd much prefer that it point the local **Negative Y-axis** instead.

I'd prefer to not change the x,y,z axes of the model itself, as I feel that's going to be a pain to deal with when I'm applying other logic to the person object.

Is there a way to change which axis lookAt() uses? Or am I going to have to roll my own lookAt() function? Thanks ~

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to change which axis lookAt() uses?

No, the default local `forward` vector for 3D objects (excluding cameras) is `(0, 0, 1)`. Unlike other engines, `three.js` does not allow to configure the `forward` vector, only the `up` vector. But this is not really helpful in your case.

You can try to transform the geometry in order to achieve a similar effect.

If you don't want to do this for some reasons and you still want to use `Object3D.lookAt()`, you have to compute a different target vector (so not the cylinder's center).

Comment: I have this problem as well, I want the object's local x axis to point at the lookAt coords. You're suggestion is to find a new lookAt target? Could you describe what the new x,y,z would would be? Thanks!

Comment: When I beam into the codepen, there is no run button and it does not auto-run. How can I run it? Sorry to be codepen noob!

Comment: [self-explanation] "the default local forward vector for 3D objects (excluding cameras) is (0, 0, 1)": from the three.js code I understand that for cameras and lights, the local forward vector is (0, 0, -1).

Comment: Only cameras have a different forward vector.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the forward vector of the `lookAt` method can't be changed (as @Mugen87 said), you can still adjust the local rotation afterwards by knowing in advance the difference between the forward Z axis used, and the axis you consider your mesh to be "upward" (ex: a person standing up on the Y axis).

Basically, in your case, just add this line after the `lookAt` method :

```js
mesh.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), Math.PI * -0.5 );
```

And the cone will look up :)